# Include "created" option for top user posts link

Tags: feature-request, bug, search, top-users

In the [tag's top users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/topusers) you can see as **All Time** top users as well as **Last 30 days** top users. Link from the post count refers to the search request, and doesn't work as expected for **Last 30 days** section. E.g. I see "8 answers provided" in the tooltip for "8" number near Shog9:

> [image: Shog8]

But the search request returns all Shog's answers:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:811%20[bug]%20is:answer

For the current time there are 296 results. This is slightly more than 8, isn't it?

Thereby I suggest to add a `created:30d..` option to the search request to reflect the actual post count.

You can try this:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A811+[bug]+is%3Aanswer+created%3A30d..

Comment: As a minimum it should prefer the "[Newest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a811%20%5bbug%5d%20is%3aanswer)" tab instead of the "Relevance" tab, presumably all the results would be relevant.